# Too Many Requests: retry after 8

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Сегодня не удается опубликовать медиафайлы ботом в Телеграм. Всё время выдается "Too Many Requests: retry after 8". Похоже на баг Телеграм, но подтверждения найти не удалось.
Менялись ли у Телеграм лимиты на постинг? Эти лимиты существуют как для ботов, так и платформ, где эти боты работают?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this

Comment: Я забыл уточнить, что публикации ведутся от множества ботов и у всех была эта ошибка. Через несколько часов баг пропал.